# How to animate zoom in a 3d scatterplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I am a student and I am new to matplotlib animation.

I am trying to figure out how to animate zooming in towards the center of my 3d scatterplot, and I've included my code below. I am trying to get the zeroes to be at the middle of each axis so I am able to see the overall plot as a zoom in. I don't get an error whenever I run my code but when I run the animation the intervals change abruptly and don't seem to go in a certain pattern. Another thing I've noticed is that the zeroes are only sometimes in the middle of the axis, while the plot "glitches out".

Thank You.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

import matplotlib.animation as animation
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
%matplotlib notebook


x = np.random.rand(100)*100 
y = np.random.rand(100)*100
z = np.random.rand(100)*100

#setup figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, facecolor='LightCyan', projection = '3d')

#set up viewing window (in this case the 25 most recent values)

ax.set_xlim([-1, 1])
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
ax.set_zlim([-1,1])


#sets up list of images for animation
plot = ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='b', marker= '*',)

def func(i):

    x_lim = ax.set_xlim(-i,i)

    y_lim = ax.set_ylim(-i, i)

    z_lim = ax.set_zlim(-i, i)

    return plot

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, func, frames=100, interval=1000, blit=True)
```

Comment: The interval is 1s, meaning you get a new frame every second. The axes ticks are chosen automatically such that there are always 5 to 9 ticks at useful locations to be seen. So the result is expected. What exactly is the problem? How would you like it to be instead?

Comment: I would like to see the graph start with 0,0,0 at the center of each axis. and the initial limits being at [-1,1] for every axis. Right now it has 0,0,0 at a corner and jumps between frames instead of linearly expanding.

Comment: [This is the animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCUjd.gif) produced by the code. It starts with zero in the middle and expands linearly, as expected. I can't see any problem with that.